# TCP client and server; cmd prompt using object streams issue

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, client-server

i have one client and one server which communicates through object streams. I have another class math.java which populates methods for math calculation(like add, substract and so on). When server and client start, server displays the math.java class's funtion to display welcome message which client prints it. then user must input (a - add, s - substract and so on). fter user input server recieves it and passes to the math.java and it creates two random numbers and displays to users, then user mannually types the result, which is then checked by math.java , if its correct , it will print correct and if its incorrect, print incorrect and begin another thread in both cases. this continues till either user presses q to quit or atleast 10 times....

I'm having trouble with my client server connection. when welcomes is displayed, i press a for add, then on the server side i see that a is taken twice but it still gives me two random numbers and every thing is fine but when the server checks and prints correct or incorrect, i'm not being able to start new thread..... the client side gives me another line (blank) and then another thread starts. while the server now recieves the blank line and is ahead than client

please i need to finish this project soon, help me someone.

files are here:

client.java

public class clientRPC extends Thread {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Socket s = null;

    try {

        int serverPort = 8888;

        s = new Socket("localhost", serverPort);// server name is local host    

        clientRPC tt = new clientRPC();
        Thread thr = new Thread(tt);

        thr.start();

        //initializing input and output streams object and referencing them to get input and output
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
       // out.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true)
        {
        //reads and prints welcome message  
                        System.out.println(in.readObject());

                        //reads user input
                        String value = br.readLine();


        out.writeObject(value);
                    out.flush();

        String objstr = String.valueOf(in.readObject());
        System.out.print(objstr);
        value = br.readLine();
        out.writeObject(value);

        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Socket:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("EOF:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("readline:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("close:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

server.java

```
 public class serverRPC extends Thread {



Socket clientSocket;




public static void main (String args[]) {

    try{
        int serverPort = 8888; 
        ServerSocket listen_socket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = listen_socket.accept();
            Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket);



                    serverRPC rpc = new serverRPC();
        Thread thr=new Thread(rpc);

        thr.start();
        }

    } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Listen socket:"+e.getMessage());}

}   
}

class Connection extends Thread {

ObjectInputStream in;
ObjectOutputStream out;
Socket clientSocket;

public Connection (Socket aClientSocket) {

    try {
        clientSocket = aClientSocket;
        in = new ObjectInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream());
        out =new ObjectOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        this.start();


        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Connection:"+e.getMessage());}
}

public String printMessage(InetAddress a, String s){

        String address = a.getHostAddress();
    return String.format("The Received Message from Client at address:%s\n====================================\n%s", address, s);
}

public void run(){

    try {                            

        MathsTutor mt = new MathsTutor();
                    InetAddress ip = clientSocket.getInetAddress();

        while(true)
        {
                        //display welcome message
                        out.writeObject(mt.displayOperations());


            Object obj = in.readObject();
            String objstr = String.valueOf(obj);


            if(!objstr.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
            {
                System.out.println(printMessage(ip, objstr));
                mt.setOperation(objstr);

                out.writeObject(mt.setProblem());
                //reading another input
                Object obj1 = in.readObject();
                int objint = Integer.parseInt(obj1.toString());

                out.writeObject(mt.checkAnswer(objint));

            }
            else
            {
                clientSocket.close();
            }

            // printWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        }




    }catch (EOFException e){System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage());
    } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("readline:"+e.getMessage());
    }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
    }
            finally{ try {clientSocket.close();}catch (IOException e){/*close failed*/}}


}
}
```

math.java

```
public class Math implements Serializable{

private int valueOne,valueTwo;
private char operation;
int [] problems;
SecureRandom rand;
final int SIZE = 20;



 public Math ()
  {
     problems = new int [SIZE];
     rand = new SecureRandom();

  }

  public void setProblems()
  {
     Date today = new Date();
     rand.setSeed(today.getTime());
     for (int i=0; i<problems.length;i++)
     {
         problems[i] =  10+ rand.nextInt(90);

     }
    Arrays.sort(problems);
  }
  public int [] getProblems()
  {
     return problems;
  }

  public String getStringOfNumbers()
  {
      this.setProblems();
     System.out.printf("problem length %d", Arrays.toString(problems).length());
     return Arrays.toString(problems);
  }
  public void setValueOne (int one)
  {
     this.valueOne = one;
  }
  public void setValueTwo (int two)
  {
     this.valueTwo = two;
  }

  public void setOperation (String op)
  {
     op.trim();

     char ch = op.charAt(0);
     System.out.println(op);
     char symbol = '+';
     switch (ch)
     {
        case 'A'| 'a': symbol = '+';
                            break;
         case 'S'| 's': symbol = '-';
                            break;
         case 'M'| 'm': symbol = '*';
                            break;
         case 'D'| 'd': symbol = '/';
                            break;
     }
     this.operation = symbol;
  }

    public String setProblem ()
  {
     Date today = new Date();
     rand.setSeed(today.getTime());
     setValueOne (10+ rand.nextInt(90));
     setValueTwo (10+ rand.nextInt(90));
     return String.format("%d  %d:  ", valueOne, this.valueTwo);
  }

    public String checkAnswer( int answer)
  {
     String result = " incorrect";
     switch (operation)
     {
        case '+': if (valueOne+ valueTwo ==answer )
                         result = " correct";
                      break;
        case '-': if (valueOne - valueTwo ==answer )
                         result = " correct";
                      break;
        case '*': if (valueOne / valueTwo ==answer )
                         result = " correct";
                      break;
         case '/': if (valueOne * valueTwo ==answer )
                         result = " correct";
                      break;
     }

     return result;
  }
 //display menu.
 public String displayOperations()
 {
    return String.format("\nWelcome to Maths Tutor Service."
       + " The available maths exercises are:"
       + "\n Addition: Enter 'A' or 'a' "
       + "\n Subtraction: Enter 'S' or 's' "
       + "\n Multiplication: Enter 'M' or 'm' "
       + "\n Division: Enter 'D' or 'd' "
       + "\n Enter 'Q' or 'q' to quit\n");
 }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Math one = new Math();
    System.out.println(one.displayOperations());
      String in;
    in  = input.next();
    one.setOperation(in);
    for (int i =0 ; i< 5; i++)
    {
    System.out.println( one.setProblem());
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
   System.out.println( one.checkAnswer(answer));
    }

  }
}
```

the output:

the red indicates that the server is taking input twice
and the blue is that blank space client side is adding instead of that i need the welcome to start again for atleast 10 times

[image: image is here]

Comment: You were told several days ago not to post pictures of text here, and your question was also answered. If you don't understand the answer, say so in a comment under the answer. Do not repost.

Comment: can u please check this and ignore the previous one?? i will delete that one if i have to but please help me with this one i got one day left